# waitForElementToDisappear for all the panels of the page

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

```
By panelCollapseSelector = By.cssSelector(".panel-heading+.panel-collapse");
waitForElementToDisappear(panelCollapseSelector);
```

The above code waits for the 1st panel of the page. I would like to wait for all the panels to collapse. How can I run loop around this.to wait for all the panels of the page.

code before collapse

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="height: auto;">
```

code after collapse

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
```

Comment: what does the html look like for panels that are not yet collapsed?  And for panels that have collapsed?

Comment: @BreaksSoftware added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to wait for 0 elements matching the non collapsed panels.

One possible CSS selector to get all the non collapsed panels:

```
".panel-heading:not(.in) + .panel-collapse:not(.in)"
```

Then to wait with a lambda expression :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until((WebDriver drv) -> drv.findElements(By.cssSelector(
    ".panel-heading:not(.in) + .panel-collapse:not(.in)")).size() == 0);
```

Or using the expected conditions:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
    By.cssSelector(".panel-heading:not(.in) + .panel-collapse:not(.in)"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this java method for waiting 60 seconds for all panels to get collapse

```
int timeout=60;
while(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".panel-heading+.panel-collapse")).getAttribute("style").contains("height: auto;") && timeout > 0) {                        
try {
    if(timeout>1)
        {
        timeout--;
        System.out.println("====== Waiting for Collapsing Panels ======");                               
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
       }
```